# Pass props down in Redux React app with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

Here's my entry point file:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import { syncReduxAndRouter, routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router'
import reducers from './reducers'

import App from './containers/app.jsx'
import About from './about.jsx'
import Dashboard from './dashboard/index.jsx'

const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, reducers, {
    routing: routeReducer
}))
const store = createStore(reducer)
const history = createBrowserHistory()

syncReduxAndRouter(history, store)

const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'about', component: About },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard }
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router routes={routes} history={history} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Which seems to be pretty standard from what I can gather. However, I'm a little confused about how I get props down from `App` to, for example, the `Dashboard` component. Here's the `App` component:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router'

import * as authActions from './../actions/auth'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    authActions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    authState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authState: state.authState}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        authActions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Sorry the code isn't a little more concise, but I'm specifically trying to pass the `authState` (from my Reducer) down to the `Dashboard` component, and I'm a little confused about how that works with React Router and `redux-simple-router` libs...

EDIT:

I changed the `Dashboard` component to include this at the bottom:

```
Dashboard.propTypes = {
    authActions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    authState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authState: state.authState}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        authActions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)
```

And I can now access the Redux state and actions. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it works for now...

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? Also you can also write your route object with jsx fyi

Comment: @DominicTobias 1.0.2. Yes, seem to prefer object notation though!

Answer (score 0):

Using react-router v1+ you can access props on your deepest current route with: `this.props.route`.

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path='about' component={About} />
        <Route path='dashboard' component={Dashboard} customprop="Hello, it's me" />
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
</Route>
```

In your dashboard component:

`this.props.route.customprop` => `"Hello, it's me"`

To access all the routes in your current route tree you can traverse `this.props.routes` (deepest route is last).

Comment: Aha, I had found this feature, so thank you. But I was hoping to use the props that are injected by Redux, ie. the ones accessible in App. I figured because App is my "root" component, it would/could pass down props to my `childRoutes` components

Comment: Ah ok, your connect code looks correct although you can omit `mapDispatchToProps`. You can simply dispatch actions directly if needed as you have `this.props.dispatch`. Read sentence 2 and 3 which recommend this approach: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html

Comment: @DominicTobias this works but if the prop value changes, React Router throws an error "Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored" 

(I'm passing props from the redux store and when these change, I want the new props to go to my components but it doesn't due to this warning.)

Comment: If you're using redux then I recommend you use react-redux to pass props @jeznag

Comment: Thanks Dominic. I realised I was operating under a faulty belief that I was only allowed to have one component connected to the store. Have changed to have a few `smart` components connected to store and all is good now :)